# get id dynamic inside $_POST PHP

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

Is this the right way to get ID dynamic within $_POST?

```
if( isset( $_POST['episode_title '. $episode_ID .''] ) ){
    $episode_title . $episode_ID = $_POST['episode_title '. $episode_ID .''];
}
```

using `'. $episode_ID .'` to get id dynamic.

If not, then does someone know how? thanks.

Comment: `.''` at the end of the concatenation doesn't do anything.

Comment: Don't use dynamic names, use arrays.

Comment: you should use arrays ie `name="episode_title[X]"` where `X` is your id you can then loop though your `$_POST`

Comment: We need to see the HTML to tell if you're getting the dynamic ID correctly.

Comment: But you're definitely not assigning to the variable correctly. To use a variable variable, it should be `${$episode_title . $episode_ID} =`

Comment: But it would be better to use an array: `$episode_title[$episode_id] =`

Comment: @krunos check my answer it will do what you want. _FYI: you can mark answer that helped you as the best answer_

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = $_POST;
foreach( $posts as $key => $value)
    if(preg_match('/episode_title (\d+)/', $post))
    {
        // rest...
    }
}
```